# Modify data for the post request in JS (ES6)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I hope this is not a duplicate. I have to prepare POST data for the request. 
The expected working body format is as follow:

```
{
    "type": "expense",
    "field_date_cost": {
        "und": [{
            "value": {
                "date": "16/04/2018"
            }
        }]
    },
    "field_amount": {
        "und": [{
            "value": "10"
        }]
    },
    "field_details": {
        "und": [{
            "value": "test"
        }]
    }
}
```

My HTTP POST Request is receiving data from the form in this format now.

```
{
  "field_date_cost": "05/03/2018",
  "field_amount": "10",
  "field_details": "test",
  "type": "expense"
}
```

I'm collecting the data using the code below (ES6).

```
 const field_date_cost = document.querySelector('#edit-date').value;
 const field_amount = document.querySelector('#edit-amount').value;
 const field_details = document.querySelector('#edit-details').value;
 const id = document.querySelector('#id').value;
 const type = "expense";
 const data = {
     field_date_cost,
     field_amount,
     field_details,
     type
 }
 }
```

I would like to modify each element in JS to match the required structure. I tried with `Array.prototype.map` and others.

Comment: That's a simple static layout that you have to fill with 4 values. I don't see any problems that would require `.map()` or any other method from `Array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make an object with the desired format and insert the variables at the appropriate locations:

```js
const field_date_cost = "05/03/2018";
const field_amount = '10';
const field_details = 'test';
const type = "expense";

const body = {
  "type": type,
  "field_date_cost": {
    "und": [{
      "value": {
        "date": field_date_cost
      }
    }]
  },
  "field_amount": {
    "und": [{
      "value": field_amount
    }]
  },
  "field_details": {
    "und": [{
      "value": field_details
    }]
  }
};
console.log(body);
```

Comment: Thank you for a smart answer.